# How to rename exe.win-amd64-3.8 folder in cx_Freeze after running setup.py

Tags: python, cx-freeze, python-3.8

I am using cx_Freeze python exe creator. After running the `setup.py` script, it create the directory like this `build/exe.win-amd64-3.8`. I want to rename the directory `exe.win-amd64-3.8` to `runner`. I tried with other options using `os.rename`, but it does not work if I write in setup.py and it gives error like `Permission denied`. I provide below my `setup.py` script below.

```
import shutil

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes = ["net_util","cx_Freeze","platform", "subprocess"]
excludes = ["tkinter", "test","unittest", "pydoc","http",'multiprocessing.Pool']
packages = ["os", "platform", "net_util","concurrent","subprocess","platform"]
build_exe_options = {"excludes": excludes,"optimize": 2}
mainScript = "main.py"
exeIcon = "icons/ping.ico"
exeName = "pingcheck.exe"

base = None
# if sys.platform == "win32":
#     base = "Win32GUI"


exe = Executable(script=mainScript, base = base, icon=exeIcon,targetName=exeName)
shutil.rmtree('build', ignore_errors=True)

setup(name = "pingExe",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My Ping Console application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [exe])
```

Please suggest me about how to rename when I run `python setup.py build`.

Comment: Exactly the same problem for me. Did you find a solution for this eventually? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm very late to this thread, but if anyone else ends up here...

Simply using the command `--build-exe runner` will do the trick. Also, if you use `-b [DIR]`, that will change the directory that is traditionally `build\.`

Putting it all together: `python setup.py build -b . --build-exe runner` will remove the `build\` directory and instead simply leave the executable and its dependencies in `runner` within your current working directory.

Alternatively, you can add `"build_exe": runner` as another keyword argument within your `build_exe_options` which will do the equivalent of `-b . --build-exe runner`. This should look like:

```
# Stuff before here...
build_exe_options = {
  "build_exe": "runner",
  "excludes": excludes,
  "optimize": 2
}
# More after...
setup(
  name="pingExe",
  version="0.1",
  description="My Ping Console application!",
  options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
  executables=[exe]
)
```